# How can I move an image upwards in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get an image to move upwards. The problem is that the code I've added doesn't work.

```css
img src="arrow_inv.png" {
      animation-duration: 2.4s;
      animation-name: arrow;
    }

    @keyframes arrow {
      from {
        float: right; margin: 28em -4em 1em 1em;
      }

      to {
        float: right; margin: 8em -4em 1em 1em;
      }
    }
```

```html
<img src="arrow_inv.png" style="float: right; margin: 28em -4em 1em 1em;" width="100px" height="75px">
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Is this you actual selector: `img src="arrow_inv.png" {` ?

Comment: Ive also tried giving it an id and using that. I only want to assign the animation to one image.

Comment: well it's [working here](https://jsfiddle.net/sun6vx5w/) (with a correct selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `img[src="..."]`. You can read [some examples of attribute selector on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).  Next time when debugging simple cases, you can simplify it as much as possible, and make it work, and then add more to it. For example, in this case you can make it just `img { ... }` since there is only one image, and see that it worked, and you will know the part `img src="arrow_inv.png"` needs fixing.

You may or may not want the right negative margin depending on what you'd like to do.

```css
img[src="https://i.imgur.com/j7Ie7pg.jpg"] {
  animation-duration: 2.4s;
  animation-name: arrow;
}

@keyframes arrow {
  from {
    float: right;
    margin: 28em -4em 1em 1em;
  }
  to {
    float: right;
    margin: 2em -4em 1em 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/j7Ie7pg.jpg" style="float: right; margin: 28em -4em 1em 1em;" width="100px" height="75px">
```